# Can I run with a computer in my backpack?

Tags: ssd, laptop-repair

*This maybe a tad off-topic, but as it says on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange), hardware questions should be fine on Super User.*

I want to run home from work (~20 min of jogging) but I need to bring with me my laptop, a Macbook Pro with an SSD drive.

I there a risk of hardware damage—in short or longterm—if I keep the computer in my backpack while running?

Comment: Should be fine. You might want to consider carrying scissors too, though, to be extra safe.

Comment: Walk but don't run! Run but don't stumble! stumble but don't fall on your backpack! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always some risk when doing anything with your laptop. As long as your only drive is the SSD then it should be rock solid.

Optical drives wouldn’t like this kind of shock so much but will actually survive fairly well (I’m basing this on the fact that 20 years ago I owned a Discman which I used for running).

I *believe* that the laptop you are using uses LED backlighting. If this is the case then it should be fairly shock resistant. Unless I’m missing something, it should be fairly safe. But be careful with it though. don’t let other objects in your backpack crush it. Breaking the screen is really the main concern I would have.

Comment: Yep, any vibration will eventually (over perhaps thousands of hours of running) lead to some sort of component failure.  But absent a hard drive, optical drive, or some other large mechanical component (and assuming a backpack that pads well, without "rattling") running to/from work should not be a problem.

Comment: Sounds reasonable that the screen would be the main concern. A college with a laptop of the same model broke his screen by lifting up the computer very fast when someone spilled coffee next to it (not on it). Warranty covered though.